# Find which fields in CSV are over X characters

Tags: bash, csv

I have a CSV file that I parse with a self written bash-script. The contents of a field in lets say the second column may not contain more than 50 characters.
How can I find those fields and list them, including their line number? And can I trim them to 50 characters?

For example:

```
100245;this field may not contain more than fifty characters;12;Y
```

should be shortened to

```
100245;this field may not contain more than fifty charac;12;Y
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk -v len=50 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} length($2)>len {$2=substr($2, 1, len)} 1' file
```

This will find all fields greater than length in argument (50) and trim those fields down to 50 using `substr` function.

Comment: Is it also possible to check each column in a csv file? Lets say all the fields in column 1 may contain no more than 6 characters, column 2 max 12, column 3 max 25, etc.

Comment: Yes you can use for example: `awk -v len1=6 -v len2=50 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} length($1)>len1 {$1=substr($1, 1, len1)} length($2)>len2 {$2=substr($2, 1, len2)} 1' file`

Comment: Ok, that's quite obvious! ;-) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` with a 50 length:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$2=sprintf("%.50s", $2)}1' file
100245;this field may not contain more than fifty charact;12;Y
100245;this field may not ters;12;Y
```

From [awk's guide - Modifiers for printf Formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html):

```
.prec

    %s

        Maximum number of characters from the string that should print.
```

---

Other examples:

```
$ echo "asdfasdf" | awk '{printf "%.10s\n", $1}'
asdfasdf
$ echo "asdfasdf" | awk '{printf "%.5s\n", $1}'
asdfa
```

Comment: no, I think your trimming is perfectly valid. In fact, get a +1 for it :)

Comment: I usually don't use `sprintf` for trimming so thanks for showing a good use of it. +1

Answer (score 0):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/^\([^;]*;[^;]\{49\}\)[^;]*/\1/' file
100245;this field may not contain more than fifty charac;12;Y
```